# How to iterate a tableView in Javafx or Scalafx?

Tags: javafx, tableview, scalafx

I am quite new at Scala. I use a tableView that has the custom type "Constraint", and I need to iterate it by the row.

Here is where I have gotten so far:

```
class ConstraintView(val stage : Stage) {

var obs : ObservableBuffer[Constraint]=ObservableBuffer()

var listConst : List[ConstraintTrait]=List()

val checkColumn=new TableColumn[Constraint, java.lang.Boolean] {
text = ""
cellValueFactory=_.value.initialSelection.delegate
}

checkColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(checkColumn))



stage.title="Constraint Table View"
stage.scene=new Scene {

 val tab=new TableView[Constraint](obs) {
    editable=true
    columns ++=List(checkColumn,
      new TableColumn[Constraint, String] {
        text="Constraint Name"
        cellValueFactory=_.value.constraintNameProp

      },
      new TableColumn[Constraint, String] {
        text = "Result"
        cellValueFactory=_.value.resultProp
      }

    )
  }


 content=tab

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you would do

```
for (Constraint c : tab.getItems()) {
    // do something with c
}
```

or

```
tab.getItems().forEach(c -> {
    // do something with c
});
```

I don't know Scala, but perhaps this is enough for you to be able to translate.

Comment: thanx but what i need exactly is to set a tooltip for each row of tableview.

Comment: That's not the question you asked, though, and you can't do that by iterating through the table.